# Show JPanel in JFrame with Parameter [QUIZZ]

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Hello i have some problem i want to create a quizz,When i click play game i want to add a JPanel to my JFrame GameGUI and replace name of button and set a question and when i click in button i pass in the next question ( Quizz :/ ) but the JPanel is not showed in my JFrame. 
Sorry for my English :'(

Here is the code of Main Class :

```
 public class Module extends JFrame implements DocumentListener {

        private static boolean run;

        public static  ArrayList <Question> QuestionList = new ArrayList <Question>(); 
    public static  ArrayList <QuizzF> PanelList = new ArrayList <QuizzF>();
        public static  GUI GameGUI = new GUI();
        public static  JPanel content = new JPanel();
        public static final CardLayout card = new CardLayout();



    public Module() {
         initComponents();

         jTextField1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("QuizzWinner - Categorie");
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 488));
        setResizable(false);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel2.setText("CONNAISANCE");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2);
        jLabel2.setBounds(110, 228, 110, 80);

        jButton2.setText("PLAY");
        jButton2.setEnabled(false);
        getContentPane().add(jButton2);
        jButton2.setBounds(435, 310, 73, 23);

        jButton3.setText("PLAY");
        jButton3.setEnabled(false);
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton3);
        jButton3.setBounds(110, 140, 73, 23);

        jTextField1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR));
        jTextField1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(5, 10));
        getContentPane().add(jTextField1);
        jTextField1.setBounds(20, 420, 160, 20);

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel3.setText("SPORT");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel3);
        jLabel3.setBounds(290, 70, 80, 60);

        jLabel8.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel8.setText("Your Name :");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel8);
        jLabel8.setBounds(20, 390, 120, 30);

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel4.setText("MEDCINE");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel4);
        jLabel4.setBounds(285, 218, 80, 100);

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel5.setText("CULTURE GENERAL");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel5);
        jLabel5.setBounds(420, 228, 130, 80);

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel6.setText("CINEMA");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel6);
        jLabel6.setBounds(450, 40, 90, 110);

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel7.setText("ETUDE");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel7);
        jLabel7.setBounds(130, 70, 80, 60);

        jButton5.setText("PLAY");
        jButton5.setEnabled(false);
        getContentPane().add(jButton5);
        jButton5.setBounds(435, 140, 73, 23);

        jButton4.setText("PLAY");
        jButton4.setEnabled(false);
        getContentPane().add(jButton4);
        jButton4.setBounds(273, 140, 73, 23);

        jButton6.setText("PLAY");
        jButton6.setEnabled(false);
        getContentPane().add(jButton6);
        jButton6.setBounds(110, 310, 73, 23);

        jButton7.setText("PLAY");
        jButton7.setEnabled(false);
        getContentPane().add(jButton7);
        jButton7.setBounds(273, 310, 73, 23);

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("jk.jpg")); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1);
        jLabel1.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 460);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         



       content.setLayout(card);
       addToArray("QuestionBank.txt");
       buildPanel();
       playGamelopp();
       System.exit(0);


    }                                        



        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {     
            if(jTextField1.getText().length() >= 5){

            jButton2.setEnabled(true);
            jButton3.setEnabled(true);
            jButton4.setEnabled(true);
            jButton5.setEnabled(true);
            jButton6.setEnabled(true);
            jButton7.setEnabled(true);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {     
           if(jTextField1.getText().length() < 5){
                jButton2.setEnabled(false);

            jButton3.setEnabled(false);
            jButton4.setEnabled(false);
            jButton5.setEnabled(false);
            jButton6.setEnabled(false);
            jButton7.setEnabled(false);  
        }
        }


        private static void addToArray(String Lien) {

        try {
            FileReader QuestionFile = new FileReader (Lien);    
            BufferedReader Reader = new BufferedReader(QuestionFile);
            FileReader LineReader = new FileReader(Lien);

            LineNumberReader LineNumber = new LineNumberReader(LineReader); 
            LineNumber.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);                               // Not sure why this line here; ask someone
            int numQuestions = (LineNumber.getLineNumber() + 1) / 6;       // +1 because it starts counting at 0, divide by 6 because 6 lines per question
                 LineNumber.close();                                           

            for (int j=0; j < numQuestions; j++){ 
                Question NewQuestion = new Question(Reader.readLine(), Reader.readLine(), Reader.readLine(), Reader.readLine(), Reader.readLine(), Reader.readLine());
                QuestionList.add(NewQuestion);

            }

        } catch (IOException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "We have encountered an error. Please confirm that the QuestionFile has not been removed from the game directory.\n\n");
            System.exit(0);          
      } 
    }

        private static void buildPanel() {

        for (int i=0; i < QuestionList.size(); ++i) {
                   Question Q = QuestionList.get(i);
                   QuizzF NewPanel = new QuizzF (Q.getQuestion(), Q.getOptionA(), Q.getOptionB(),Q.getOptionC(), Q.getOptionD(), Q.getCorrectOption());
                   PanelList.add(NewPanel);
                   content.add(NewPanel, Integer.toString(i)); 
        }
                  GameGUI.setVisible(true);

        }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Module.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(Module::new);
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private static void playGamelopp() {

        refreshGUI();

        for (int i =0; i < 15; i++) {
            run = true;
            while(run) {
                card.show(content, Integer.toString(i));
                if(run) {
                    System.out.println("void");
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
}
    private static void refreshGUI() {

        GameGUI.add(content);
        GameGUI.repaint();
        GameGUI.revalidate();

    }

    public static void setRun(boolean setVal) {
        run = setVal;
    }

}
```

And There we have JPanel form with Label and 2 buttons

```
public class QuizzF extends JPanel {

private static String Question;
private String OptionA;
private String OptionB;
private String OptionC;
private String OptionD;
    private static String Correct;


public QuizzF(String Question, String OptionA, String OptionB, String OptionC, String OptionD, String CorrectOption) {
        initComponents();

    HashMap <String, JButton> buttons = new HashMap<String, JButton>();

    this.setQuestion(Question);
    this.setOptionA(OptionA);
    this.setOptionB(OptionB);
    this.setOptionC(OptionC);
    this.setOptionD(OptionD);
    this.setCorrect(CorrectOption);

            jLabel1.setText(Question);
            A.setText(OptionA);
            B.setText(OptionB);
            C.setText(OptionC);
            D.setText(OptionD);


    buttons.put("A", A);
    buttons.put("B", B);
    buttons.put("C", C);
    buttons.put("D", D);

    customizeButtons(buttons);      

}

private static void customizeButtons(HashMap <String, JButton> buttons) {

    for(HashMap.Entry<String, JButton> entry: buttons.entrySet()) { 

        String name = entry.getKey();
        JButton b = entry.getValue();

        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Question = "+getQuestion()+"");
                 System.out.println("Name = "+name+"");
                                     System.out.println("Correct Answer = "+getCorrect()+"");

                if(name.equals(getCorrect())){

                    b.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    //Module.incrementScore();  
                }

                else {
                    b.setBackground(Color.RED);
                }

                Module.setRun(false);
            }
        });
    }
}

public static String  getQuestion() {
    return Question;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    Question = question;
}

public String getOptionA() {
    return OptionA;
}

public void setOptionA(String optionA) {
    OptionA = optionA;
}

public String getOptionB() {
    return OptionB;
}

public void setOptionB(String optionB) {
    OptionB = optionB;
}

public String getOptionC() {
    return OptionC;
}

public void setOptionC(String optionC) {
    OptionC = optionC;
}

public String getOptionD() {
    return OptionD;
}

public void setOptionD(String optionD) {
    OptionD = optionD;
}

public static String getCorrect() {
    return Correct;
}

public void setCorrect(String correct) {
    Correct = correct;
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    A = new javax.swing.JButton();
    B = new javax.swing.JButton();
    C = new javax.swing.JButton();
    D = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 400));
    setName(""); // NOI18N

    A.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(30, 37, 81));
    A.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    A.setText("Reponse 1");
    A.setToolTipText("");
    A.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.MatteBorder(null));
    A.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

    B.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(30, 37, 81));
    B.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    B.setText("Reponse 2");
    B.setToolTipText("");
    B.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.MatteBorder(null));

    C.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(30, 37, 81));
    C.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    C.setText("Reponse 3");
    C.setToolTipText("");
    C.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.MatteBorder(null));

    D.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(30, 37, 81));
    D.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    D.setText("Reponse 4");
    D.setToolTipText("");
    D.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.MatteBorder(null));

    jLabel1.setText("Internet tendent à reproduire le même extrait sans fin, ce qui fait de lipsum.com le seul vrai générateur de Lorem Ipsum.");
    jLabel1.setToolTipText("");
    jLabel1.setAutoscrolls(true);

    jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("home3.jpg")); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(190, 190, 190)
            .addComponent(A, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 220, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(190, 190, 190)
            .addComponent(B, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 220, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(190, 190, 190)
            .addComponent(C, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 220, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(190, 190, 190)
            .addComponent(D, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 220, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(20, 20, 20)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 560, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        .addComponent(jLabel2)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(120, 120, 120)
            .addComponent(A, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(10, 10, 10)
            .addComponent(B, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(220, 220, 220)
            .addComponent(C, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(270, 270, 270)
            .addComponent(D, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        .addComponent(jLabel2)
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton A;
private javax.swing.JButton B;
private javax.swing.JButton C;
private javax.swing.JButton D;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 4) Remove all instances of `static` keyword for GUI components, as well as any other one where you cannot explain ..

Comment: .. why the application design actually requires `static`. The use of `static` in GUIs more often causes problems, than solves them.

Comment: As to the crux of the problem, is sounds like better approaches might be either a) use a `CardLayout` that contains all possible question, then flick to each one as needed, ***or*** b) only have a single 'question' container, and with each new question, simply update the labels and fields in that one container to reflect the details of the new question. I think (b) is the better approach, but cannot be sure until I see an MCVE / SSCCE.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I admit that I have not posted all the code in full for fear that it will be big, but I come to edit by postulating it all

Comment: *"I have not posted all the code"* Good. Nobody has time to trawl through the entire code base looking for errors. That is why I suggested you post an MCVE / SSCCE. I suspect you either did not read, or did not understand, the documents linked. Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was related with the threads, I created a new thread and called the `Main` class like this :

```
new SwingWorker() {

 @Override
  protected Object doInBackground() throws Exeption {

   return new Main();

   }

  }.execute();
```